# Blocking numbers from being entered into a text input

Tags: javascript

I need to make a form for my school work as a part of my website, and I've already did the form and many validation but one thing I can't do is number validation, for example in the first name box I want it to check if numbers were entered and if so it will send an error, and I can't do it, I can only make it send an error when a number was entered but not when a number and a string were entered, I searched this website and found answers which I couldn't understand..
This is the code for the button, and text input

```
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /> <input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Try it" />
```

This is the script the basic of the script:

```
  function myFunction() {
        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    }
```

Now I want that if the var (firstname) contains any numbers an error("can't use numbers") message will be sent, how do I do it?

Comment: This is called "form field validation". Googling for how to do this by using "HTML5 form field validation" gives me http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation as first hit, and contains all the information you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's comment in your question is helpful . . . HTML5 form validation is definitely going to be the way going forward.

That being said, there are still plenty of older browsers that don't support HTML5 yet floating around out there, so a JS solution might be what you are looking for here.

In this case, I'd recommend a RegExp check to see if the value meets your criteria:

```
var regexNumberPattern = new RegExp("[0-9]");

if (regexNumberPattern.test(firstname)) {
    . . . do error stuff . . .
}
else {
    . . . do valid value stuff (if anything) . . .
}
```

The RegExp pattern basically says "find any characters between 0 and 9".  By using `.test(STRING_VAL)`, you are testing that pattern against a specific value (in this case, the "firstname" input value).  `.test()` will return `true` if it finds the pattern in the string or `false` if it doesn't.

Based on the response that you get, you can do any additional logic that you would like to handle the error (or lack thereof).

Comment: Thanks, works great and it was simple and easy, got it!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to evaluate your resulting string against a regular expression to see that it only contains letters and spaces (or whatever characters you allow.)

Setup your regex like this:

```
var myReg = RegExp('^[A-Za-z ]+$');
var valid = myReg.test(firstname)
```

You can use whatever regular expression you want (and my reg-fu is weak, so feel free to accept better expressions offered by others.)

A helpful tool I found is at [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/).  You can plug in a regular expression and test what it does (though you still have to know some secrets, like `^` means first character and `$` means last character.)

**EDIT**

I think a great guide for regular expressions is at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Regular expressions are really just a string that explains a certain 'pattern' of text that can be checked for; in this case, you can check that your string matches the 'pattern' of 'only contains letters and spaces'.  The patterns themselves have their own custom syntax and can look weird, but once you understand the syntax better they're usually pretty easy to parse (though the Internet is full of crazy ones, too).

The expression I wrote literally says "A string only passes the test if, starting with the first character (`^`), it contains one or more(`+`) characters from the given list (A-Z, and a-z, and spaces) and **ONLY** characters from that list, and then the string ends."

Talemyn's expression might work better, because it checks for the presence of a number and fails, which sounds like what you were looking for.

Comment: Can you guys explain me more about regular expression because I want to understand what I'm doing not just remembering it

Comment: That assumes that only letters are allowed.  He only said that numbers weren't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check for letters
try `/^[a-zA-Z]*$/`

Comment: Can you guys explain me more about regular expression because I want to understand what I'm doing not just remembering it.

Comment: That assumes that only letters are allowed.  He only said that numbers weren't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{0,100}">
```

You can use the pattern to restrict into any fixed pattern.
More help:

[Pattern Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: That assumes that only letters are allowed. He only said that numbers weren't allowed.

Comment: I wrote "You can use the pattern to restrict into any fixed pattern." This pattern can be modified into anything. It's an example. All allowable characters can be written there. @talemyn

Comment: Fair enough . . . might be confusing though, since your sample pattern that handles a question that is very similar (though not identical) to what he is looking for.

Comment: How can I make the pattern send a message inside a <p> instead of the error he's making now?

Comment: @user3108378 I guess you can't. I don't know if any solution regarding that error massage is out there or not.